# How to display the checkbox value on same page without submit button and form in php?

Tags: php, html, ajax, checkbox

I have a checkbox and If any user selects the check box then the value of checkbox will display on the same page without refresh the page.

**index.php**

```
<input  type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $value;?>" name="value_r" id="value_r"/>

if(!isset($_POST['value_r']))
echo $_POST['value_r'];
}
```

If ajax is good then can any one know how to display the value with ajax?

```
$("#value_r").change(function () {
    var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked") ? 1:0;
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        async: true,
        data: { isChecked: isChecked },
        success: function (response) {
        }
    });
  });
```

Comment: you don't need ajax to display it. If you are using jQuery, you can simply use `$("desiredElement").append(yourValueHere)`and it will be shown on that element

Comment: Data you are passing as `isChecked` and retrieving as `$_POST['value_r']`. Suspicious to me.

Comment: `if(!isset($_POST['value_r']))
echo $_POST['value_r'];
}`  if value not set display the value? That's interesting.

Comment: @N.Ivanov, With Jquery, can't pass the value to PHP. Right?

Comment: You can pass it via ajax, but if you just want to display it on the page why would you pass it back to the server??

Comment: @NanaPartykar, I tried PHP and AJAX. PHP code is different and AJAX code is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `ajax` or any `javascript` you can do this using `CSS`. check updated snippet below..

```css
input[type=checkbox] + label{
    display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<input  type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $value;?>" name="value_r" id="value_r"/><label for="">Checkbox value Comes here</label>
```

Comment: Good One. Your code is working.upvote from my side. Simple and easy code

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of the checkboxes item by **document.getElementsByName("checkme")[0].**

Comment: I have to pass that value to PHP.

Comment: $(function() {
    $("#frm1").onchange(function() {
        $("input.test[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
            alert($(this).val());
        });

        return false;
    });
});

Answer (score 0):

```js
function test(){
  v = document.getElementById("chkbx").value;
  document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = v;
}
```

```html
<input  type="checkbox" id="chkbx" value="1" onclick="test()" name="value_r" id="value_r"/>

<div id="val"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying MR.Zico, Then How can we pass the value to PHP?

Comment: @NarendraVerma You already did it to your question via AJAX. Though this wasn't your question

Comment: With the help of ajax we can pass the value to PHP. but your code is totally Script.

Comment: I assume your `input` field is already in a form in PHP or HTML. So I provide JS to show it in page without submit. And you can pass the form data by AJAX/form submit whatever you wish